# I'm looking for a way to save data to a wordpress database so they can be shown

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I've been working on a portal website (still running on localhost).
One of my pages contains a form. When the form is filled i want it to be shown on another page. I only know how to echo the form's info. Could someone help me? This is the code i've been using:

```
<?php echo "php">"."Bedrijf: ".$_POST["naam_bedrijf"].'
' ;
echo "Website: ".$_POST["website"].'
' ;
?>
```

I could really use some help. this is the first time i've tryed something like this...
Thank u!

Comment: This question really really needs more detail.

Comment: I just want the form to save the filled info and then echo it. Now it just echo's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your form action goes to the same php file which you are using to display the form data. If, yes then you can use the code as below

```
<?php echo "Bedrijf: ".$_POST['naam_bedrijf'];
echo "Website: ".$_POST['website'];
?>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank u for the response but the problem is that it echo's... But when i refresh the page the filled in data is gone :/. So i was looking for something that could store the filled data from the form in a database (wordpress) and then echo the stored info

Comment: choose a plugin to save data of form similar to [link] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/). It will store your data to database then you can easily fetch the database table which this plugin will create to your website.